# Can't find files in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to work with some `json` and `csv` files in my django project but it never found they.

I created a static folder and inside it I have create a new one called data with the different files. But when I call it, the message is always the same, it can't found the path of my files.

> [Errno 2] File b'data/data.csv' does not exist: b'data/data.csv'

Inside `settings.py` I have this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Somebody knows what I'm doing wrong?

An example how I call my `csv` file:

```
def dataframex():
    data_csv = pd.read_csv('data/data.csv')
    print(data_csv)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv()` has no idea about Django's `staticfiles` configuration.

Assuming you're using local static files and not e.g. something backed by S3 or something more esoteric, you can use [`finders.find()` to locate the real file on disk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#finders-module):

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders


def dataframex():
    csv_path = finders.find('data/data.csv')
    data_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
    print(data_csv)
```

However, for static files you don't need to directly serve to the user, such as this one, it's better to just store them in your application directory.

Assuming `myapp/views.py` contains the above, you can move `data.csv` to `myapp/data.csv`, then use

```py
csv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.csv')
```

to locate the file.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! And If I want to open a Json file instead of csv, is the same?

Comment: Yes, naturally.